# How to solve this problem with responsive - blank space on right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, mobile-website

I'm teaching coding in Visual Studio Code, and I found some template and tried make website. After finishing coding I have problem with responsive which u can see on pictures. There is blank white space and I dont know how to fix it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jvI4.jpg

I tried to change values on @media in CSS, but nothing changes. I would really like someone to help me so I know in future where I made a mistake. I also have this reset.css - that is bootstrap.
Thanks in regards.

```js
/* for navigation*/
var dugme = document.getElementById('dugmeNav');
dugme.addEventListener('click',pokreni,false);

function pokreni() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").classList.toggle("meni_sirina");
    document
      .querySelector(".meni-dugmici")
      .classList.toggle("meni-dugmici_style");
  }
```

```css
/* FONTOVI */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  src: url('../fontovi/Raleway.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url('../fontovi/OpenSans.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  src: url('../fontovi/Poppins.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  src: url('../fontovi/Roboto.ttf');
}

/* KRAJ FONTOVA */
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #0c0c0c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.margine {
  margin: 90px 0;
}

.padding {
  padding: 90px 0;
}

.padding2 {
  padding: 45px 0;
}

.padding2-top {
  padding-top: 45px;
}

.padding2-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}

.padding-top {
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.padding-bottom {
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.naslovi h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #1d1e31;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.naslovi h2::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #8547ca;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 0;
}

.hero_next_section-margin {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

/*header section*/
.omotac {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%, #f2f7fd), color-stop(45%, #1d1e31));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f2f7fd 50%, #1d1e31 45%);
}

.sub_page .omotac {
  height: auto;
}

#header_sekcija .sekcija {
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}

#header_sekcija .nav_container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigacija-sekcija.navbar-prosirenje .navbar-nav .nav-link img {
  width: 22px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.navigacija-sekcija.navbar-prosirenje .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding: 0px 25px;
  color: #fefeff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.meni-dugmici {
  z-index: 9;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 14px;
}

.meni-dugmici button {
  margin-top: 12px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.meni-dugmici span {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 7px 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.meni-dugmici .meni-dugmici .s-2 {
  -webkit-transition: all .1s;
  transition: all .1s;
}

.meni-dugmici_style button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 29px;
  top: 14px;
}

.meni-dugmici_style button .s-1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(17px);
          transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(17px);
}

.meni-dugmici_style button .s-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
          transform: translateX(100px);
}

.meni-dugmici_style button .s-3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-17px);
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-17px);
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay-sadrzaj {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.meni_sirina {
  width: 100%;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: initial;
}

.btn,
.btn:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.navigacija-sekcija .nav_search-btn {
  background-image: url(../slike/search-icon.png);
  background-size: 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 40px 0 15px;
  background-position: center;
}

.navbar-logo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.navbar-logo img {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.navbar-logo h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #8547ca;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.navigacija-sekcija {
  z-index: 99999;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.navigacija-sekcija .navbar-toggler {
  outline: none;
}

.navigacija-sekcija .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url(../slike/menu.png);
  background-size: 55px;
}

.quote_btn-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #fc5d35;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*end header section*/
/* contact section */
.kontakt_sekcija {
  background-color: #f2f7fd;
}

.kontakt_sekcija h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #010103;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.kontakt_sekcija .row {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.kontakt_sekcija input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.kontakt_sekcija input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.kontakt_sekcija input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.kontakt_sekcija input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.kontakt_sekcija input::placeholder {
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.kontakt_form-container #posaljiDugme {
  border: none;
  background-color: #8c60bd;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#kontaktnaslov {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #010103;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.contact_img-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.contact_img-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* end contact section */
/* info section */
.info_sekcija {
  background-color: #363636;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.info_sekcija h4 {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.info_logo-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.info_logo-box h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 35px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #8547ca;
}

.info_sekcija ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.info_sekcija ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.info_sekcija ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.info_sekcija ul li a:hover {
  color: #8547ca;
}

.info_sekcija .form_container input {
  width: 225px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.info_sekcija .form_container::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc8c8;
}

.info_sekcija .form_container:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc8c8;
}

.info_sekcija .form_container::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc8c8;
}

.info_sekcija .form_container::placeholder {
  color: #ccc8c8;
}

.info_sekcija .form_container .pretplataDugme {
  background-color: #8c60bd;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mreze_container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #898989;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.info_sekcija .social-box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.info_sekcija .social-box img {
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* end info section */
/* footer section*/
.footer_sekcija {
  background-color: #8547ca;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer_sekcija p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fefdfc;
}

.footer_sekcija a {
  color: #fefdfc;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px) {


  .slajder_sekcija .img-box img {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .detalji-box h2 {
      font-size: 4.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {

  .slajder_sekcija .detalji-box h2 {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .detalji-box h3 {
      font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .carousel-control-prev {
      top: 15px;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .carousel-control-next {
      bottom: 75px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
  .omotac {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f7fd 50%, #1d1e31 45%);
  }

  .sub_page .omotac {
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f7fd 50%, #f2f7fd 45%);
  }

  .omotac {
      height: auto;
  }

  .meni-dugmici span {
      background-color: #1d1e31;
  }

  .meni-dugmici_style button span {
      background-color: #fff;
  }

  .carousel-indicators {
      display: none;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .img-box {
      margin-top: 22.5px;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .carousel-control-prev,
  .slajder_sekcija .carousel-control-next {
      display: none;
  }

  .skidanje_sekcija .main-img-box {
      margin-top: 22.5px;
  }

  .onama_sekcija {
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)), url("../slike/about-bg.jpg");
  }

  .onama_sekcija .detalji-box {
      text-align: left;
      height: auto;
  }

  .onama_sekcija .detalji-box.b-1 a {
      margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .onama_sekcija .detalji-box.b-1 {
      margin-bottom: 22.5px;
  }

  .info_sekcija .col-md-3 {
      padding: 10px 12.50px;
      text-align: left;
  }

  .contact_img-box {
      margin-top: 22.5px;
  }

  .kol-levo {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
  }
  .kol-desno {
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 180px;
  }

  .b-3 p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #8c60bd;
  }

  .b-4 p {
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #8c60bd;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .kontakt_sekcija input {
      width: 100%;
  }

  .info_sekcija .social-box {
      width: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .slajder_sekcija .detalji-box h3 {
      font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .slajder_sekcija .detalji-box h2 {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  .pretplata_sekcija form {
      flex-direction: column;
  }

  .pretplata_sekcija form input {
      width: 100%;
      height: 45px;
  }

  .pretplata_sekcija form .pretplataDugme {
      width: 150px;
      height: 45px;
      line-height: 45px;
      margin-top: 25px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 376px) {
  .kol-levo {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .kol-desno {
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .b-3 p {
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .b-4 p {
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
      max-width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>Abdans - Kontakt</title>

  <!-- slajder css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stil.css">

</head>

<body>
  
    <!-- Header deo -->
    <div class="omotac">
    <header class="header_sekcija">
      <div class="sekcija">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-prosirenje navigacija-sekcija">
          <div class="navbar-vracanje">
            <div class="meni-dugmici">
              <button id="dugmeNav">
                <span class="s-1"> </span>
                <span class="s-2"> </span>
                <span class="s-3"> </span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
              <div class="overlay-sadrzaj">
                <a href="index.html">POČETNA</a>
                <a href="onama.html">O NAMA</a>
                <a href="oceneKorisnika.html">ISKUSTVA KORISNIKA</a>
                <a href="kontakt.html">KONTAKT</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <a class="navbar-logo" href="index.html">
          <h1>
            ABDANS
          </h1>
        </a>
      </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Zavrsava se header deo -->

    <!-- kontakt -->
  <section class="kontakt_sekcija padding">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="d-flex ">
        <h2 id="kontaktnaslov">
          Kontaktirajte nas
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <form action="kontakt.php" method="get">
            <div class="kontakt_form-container">
              <div>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Ime">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Broj telefona">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-5">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Poruka">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-5">
                  <input type="submit" value="pošalji" id="posaljiDugme">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="contact_img-box">
            <img src="slike/contact-img.png" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- zavrsavaju se kontakti -->
  <!-- info  -->
  <section class="info_sekcija padding-top">
    <div class="info_logo-box">
      <h3>
        ABDANS
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container padding2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4>
            O nama
          </h4>
          <p>
            Firma se bavi prodajom BIO prehrambenih proizvoda.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4>
            Korisni linkovi
          </h4>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="http://www.organiccentar.rs/prednosti/sta-organski-proizvodi.html">
                Šta je BIO proizvod ?
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                Kako preuzeti aplikaciju ?
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="onama.html">
                O nama
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4>
            Kontaktirajte nas
          </h4>
          <p>
            Kontaktirajte nas na svim društvenim mrežama, klikom na ikonicu ispod.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">

          <div class="pretplata_container">
            <h4>
              Newsletter
            </h4>
            <div class="form_container">
              <form action="pretplata.php" method="post">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Upišite vaš email" id="preplata_provera">
                <input type="submit" value="Pretplati se" class="pretplataDugme">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="mreze_container">

        <div class="social-box">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="slike/fb.png" alt="">
          </a>

          <a href="#">
            <img src="slike/twitter.png" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="slike/linkedin.png" alt="">
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="slike/instagram.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- zavrsava se info -->
  <!-- footer -->
  <footer class="sekcija footer_sekcija"> 
  <p>
    &copy; 2022 Sva prava zadržana. Napravljen od strane 
    <a href="#">Nikole Tešića</a>
  </p> 
  </footer>
  <!-- zavrsava se footer -->
  
  <!-- javasript -->

  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/reset.js"></script>
  <script src="js/navigacija.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in regards.

Comment: What is your stil.css? I did not see it in your code. Also I did not see the bootstrap from your <head>

Comment: Stil.css is classic style.css, just codes for elements. And this reset.css its bootstrap I just renamed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `width: 100vw;` in the `body` element(or the element that have background color)